# Filter Multiple Criteria in Power BI Dax

Tags: powerbi, dax, dashboard

I am looking to create a measure for a Synoptic Table and it isn't filtering as intended.

I have a list of 4 statuses with one being "L3" and I want to check the value from the "VALUE" column for any instance of "Required" or "Submitted" for a particular ID. It works only if *every* value is Required/Submitted as opposed to if *any* value is required of submitted.

Any help is greatly appreciated.

example of data:

| ID | NAME | Cx Status | VALUE |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 123 | L3 - X1 | L3 | Required |
| 123 | L3 - X2 | L3 | N/A |
| 123 | L3 - X3 | L3 | Required |

For the formula below, I'm referring to the first 2 IFs, once I look at individual "NAME" values then it works.

```
L3 States = IF(CALCULATE(COUNTROWS('master data'),

'master data'[VALUE]<>"Required"&&'master data'[VALUE]<>"Submitted",

'master data'[Cx Status]="L3"

)>0,400,

IF(CALCULATE(COUNTROWS('master data'),

'master data'[VALUE]<>"Required"&&'master data'[VALUE]<>"Submitted",

'master data'[Cx Status]="L3"

)>0,300,

IF(CALCULATE(COUNTROWS('master data'),

'master data'[VALUE]<>"Required"&&'master data'[VALUE]<>"Submitted",

'master data'[Cx Status]="L3 - X2")>0,100,

IF(CALCULATE(COUNTROWS('master data'),

'master data'[VALUE]<>"Required"&&'master data'[VALUE]<>"Submitted",

'master data'[Name]="L3 - X1")>0,50,

50))))+0
```

Comment: For reference with the data shown, the L3 States value would be 400 instead of 50.